# numpy float to int conversion returning negative values

Tags: python, numpy

I am puzzled as to why numpy.int32(np.float32(v)) returns -2147473648 (-2^31) for all values of v greater than 2^31-65.

That is:

```
numpy.int32(np.float32(2**31-65)) == 2147483520
numpy.int32(np.float32(2**31-64)) == -2147483648
numpy.int32(np.float32(2**31)) == -2147483648
numpy.int32(np.float32(3e9)) == -2147483648
numpy.int32(np.float32(3e19)) == -2147483648
```

I would expect to get the largest signed 32-bit value (2^31-1) or overflow instead of a negative value.  Conversion of large negative floats returns -2^31 as expected.  I get similar behavior with astype and asarray and also with conversion to numpy.int64 (-2^63 is returned) - conversion of large positive floating point values returns negative integer values.

This is with Python 3.10.6 and Numpy 1.23.2.

Comment: 32 bit float and 32 bit int do not occupy the same amount of memory, so the conversion process is causing the rollover to happen 64 earlier than expected.  Also you are casting into a signed int - hence the negative numbers once you exceen 2**31.  Int conversion does not have an overflow, it just drops the bits outside of the range.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy is not Python! Numpy is a bunch of C library *interfaced* with the Python language. But for example `np.int32` is a C-like 32 bits integer and has nothing to do with a multiprecision Python integer.

And C language clearly states that overflow over a signed type invokes a so called Undefined Behaviour (anything can be expected...). In common implementations (specifically in the ones used by numpy) integer types use 2-complement for negative values, and process overflow by reinterpreting the value as if it was unsigned, do the operation as unsigned (meaning wrapping around 2**32 for a 32 bits types) and convert back the unsigned representation to the signed type. Long story made short: `INT_MAX + 1` gives `INT_MIN`.

That is not all: you use a `float32` type. This type only has a 24 bits mantissa (ref: [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)). So you are using it outside of its acceptable precision zone: and here things are clear: everything going outside of the mantissa is silently dropped. If you want understandable behaviour, you should at least use `float64` here. You will still experience *integer wrapping*, but at least the operation will be accurate.